# Laravel profile update with e-mail unique:users

Tags: laravel

I'm new in Laravel. I try to make profile update page... all works good but if I try to apply rule to set email field unique:users I have problem when user try to update for example name and don't want change email.

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    ];
}
```

I want restrict that user to use the same e-mail that someone else is using... but I want to ignore that if this is the same e-mail already in that user profile and he don't want to change that.

```php
public function updateData(UpdateDataRequest $request)
{
    DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->update(array('email' => $request->email, 'name' => $request->name));

    return redirect('panel');
}
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This exact situation is used as an example in the docs.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique

> **Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:**
>
> Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check. For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the user's name, e-mail address, and location. Of course, you will want to verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of the e-mail address. You only want to throw a validation error if the user provides an e-mail address that is already used by a different user. To tell the unique rule to ignore the user's ID, you may pass the ID as the third parameter:
>
> ```
> 'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,'.$user->id
> ```
>
> If your table uses a primary key column name other than id, you may specify it as the fourth parameter:
>
> ```
> 'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,'.$user->id.',user_id'
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This answer remains true with Laravel 8 for anyone landing on this page. The email validation rule per the docs is: `unique:table,column,except,idColumn`. So, if using the default migrations, you can use it like so: `'email|unique:users,email,' . auth()->user()->id`.

Comment: @Wade the `auth()->user()->id` or `auth()->id()`, it's just lookup for the current logged-in user, and if you are trying to update another user (e.g. as an admin), this condition it is always true. Instead, you need to grab the ID of the given user instead of the logged-in one.

Answer (score 5):

*In new version. `laravel` using Rules to ignore a user or record*

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

*`$user->id` can be a specific id or the id of current user which is login*

Answer (score -1):

try to this validation(Laravel 8.x)

```
'email' => ['email:rfc','confirmed','unique:App\Models\User,email'],
```

Comment: This does not work. You included `confirmed` which requires another field for `email_confirmation`. The OP has no mention of a second email confirmation field. Passing the User model on the unique rule doesn't seem to work either..